# Msbuild command line: MSB3021 error in CopyWebApplicationLegacy task

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I've seen several questions on here about this error, but all of them seem to be related to the "Access is Denied" flavor of this error, can't find any that deal with the message I'm getting:

`C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(177,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "bin\MyApp.MyLib.dll" to "C:\Temp\Publish\staging\MyApp\MyApp_1478_5\bin\MyApp.MyLib.dll". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\MyApp.MyLib.dll'. [C:\Temp\Tags\MyApp\2011-10-27-00-NoBuildVs\src\MyApp.com\MyAppn.csproj]`

I get 30 of these errors when I build my proj. I'm building my csproj file from the command line. The proj compiles fine, it's only when it gets to the CopyWebApplicationLegacy task that things screw up. The odd thing: the app runs fine and the dlls that it is trying to copy are present in the target dir in the end. So these errors seem to have no bearing on whether the files end up where they should be or whether the app will behave correctly.

I'd consider just suppressing them, but that seems like it'll bite me later.

My command:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\Temp\Tags\MyApp\2011-10-27-00-NoBuildVs\src\MyApp.com\MyApp.csproj" /p:OutDir="C:\Temp\Publish\binOutput\" /p:WebProjectOutputDir="C:\Temp\Publish\staging\MyApp\MyApp_1478" /p:Configuration=Debug`

Tried building the solution instead of the csproj and that got the same error.

I'm stumped here. The files aren't being locked (unless they are being locked during the build somehow and released later, but it seems like I'd get a different error). What could be causing this error? I need to get this going so my automated publish can work.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from the error log: source file "bin\Debug\MyApp.MyLib.dll" should be used instead of "bin\MyApp.MyLib.dll" for Debug configuration, IMO.

Comment: OK, but how can I configure MSBuild to understand that the bin files are in a \Debug\ folder?